# Authenticate desktop application with web application (mvc web app)

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application where users can authenticate and I developed a small desktop application that needs to authenticate to the web app at startup. I don't need to call APIs from my desktop application, I just need to authenticate.

Any code samples will help taking in consideration that I am not a web developer yet. Thanks

Comment: Expose your authentication logic as an API and use it in client application.

Comment: I guess you'd need to replicate your login/authentication method? It seems like a call to an authentication API would be best. Are you also using tokens or cookies for continuous use of your actions?

Comment: Authentication at startup doesn't mean security to your application. You need to keep the authentication ticket (coockie) and send it with any other request which needs authentication. Any operation which needs to be secure, should be placed in an API on your web server and all requests to that operation should be authenticated and authorized. If you don't do that, your application will be vulnerable.

Comment: what about oauth token authentication?